# What can be the cause of Firebird server (1.5.6) Abnormal Termination

Tags: firebird

I have a server (Windows 7) machine running Firebird 1.5.6 database. It is accessed by a Delphi 7 application on the client machine running Windows 7 too.
The server is installed as SuperServer.

Very often, but on indefinite times,s the Firebird server process terminates abnormally causing the client application to freeze or to stop for 1 minute.

Does anybody has an idea what can be the cause of this situation?

Looking in the Firebird.log I can find errors like

**Firebird Abnormal Termination (4294967295)**

When this happens, the server tries to restart several times but 6-10 times in 1 minute and finally it succeeds but the client freezes or crashes.

The error log is very poor. I added BugcheckAbort = 1 in firebird config file to find out more. In meantime does anybody has an idea what is happening?

Comment: Check database file for curruption using gfix utility.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Firebird 1.5 was never tested under Windows 7. You could try Firebird 2.1(.4) or 2.5(.1) to see if this solves your problem.